# Flutter / Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find 'ExternalLinkAccount' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, build, entitlements

Since 12th october 2022, reader's app with external account management/purchase must have to declare a new entitlement.

External Link Account
Enable qualifying apps to link to an external website for account creation or management.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/external_link_account

I can't build because :

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find 'ExternalLinkAccount' in scope
```

1. Configure the SKExternalLinkAccount property list key.

```
<plist>
<dict>
    <key>SKExternalLinkAccount</key>
    <dict>
        <key>*</key>
        <string>https://example.com</string>
        <key>jp</key>
        <string>https://example.com/jp</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

2. Runner plist

```
<key>com.apple.developer.storekit.external-link.account</key>
<true/>
```

3. Runner entitlement

```
<plist>
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.storekit.external-link.account</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

4. ios build (with flutter run) :

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find 'ExternalLinkAccount' in scope
```

5. My code in a custom swift file (called with a platform specific call)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExternalLinkAccountModal: View {

    var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, world!")
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                await executeTask()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExternalLinkAccountModal_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExternalLinkAccountModal(onConfirm: nil, onCancel: nil)
            .previewDevice("iPhone 13")
            .previewInterfaceOrientation(.portrait)
    }
}



func executeTask() async {
    let basicTask = Task {
        if await ExternalLinkAccount.canOpen {
            do {
                try await ExternalLinkAccount.open()
            } catch {
                print("ExternalLinkAccount.open() error \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

6. Provisioning profile
   My provisioning profile is well configured and accepted by Apple Developper :

```
Associated Domains, External Link Account, In-App Purchase, Push Notifications
```

Can you help to fix this ?

I'm using osx Ventura and ios16 platform for developping.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to:

```swift
import StoreKit
```